# Load whole(`this`) serialized object in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class containing two hashmaps in it and want to load store the complete object of class records. I tried with the following code but 'load' method is giving error **"can not assign a variable to final variable this"**

```
class records{    
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer> > Map1 = new HashMap <>();
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer> > Map2 = new HashMap <>();

public boolean store(File f) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(this);    // THIS WORKED
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public boolean load(File f) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        this = (records) ois.readObject(); // THIS LINE GIVING ERROR

        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

    . . .
}
```

Do I need to need to write and read the two hashMap elements separately as in [Load/Store Objects in file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744962/load-store-objects-in-file-in-java)?

Comment: You cannot assign variable to `this`. Instead either set individual instance variables or create a new reference.

Comment: `this` is a final keyword in Java, and hence you can not assign any value to it. You will have to create a new instance to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign variable to this. Instead either set individual instance variables or create a new reference.

```
public records load(File f) {
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    records r1= (records) ois.readObject(); // THIS LINE GIVING ERROR

    ois.close();
    fis.close();
    return r1;
} catch (IOException e) {
    return null;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    return null;
}
return null;

. . .
```

}